# deleting records from multiple table in mysql from zend

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

How To Delete a records from multiple table in mysql using Zend framework

```
$this->_db->delete($this->_candidate_education,'candidate_id='.$id)
```

Currently i am using this query for deleting record in single table

I need to delete the records from multiple table using single delete query

Answer (score 0):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html

```
$stmt = $db->query(
                'delete FROM bugs,test WHERE reported_by = ? AND bug_status = ?',
                array('goofy', 'FIXED')
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define foreign key constraints on the tables with ON DELETE CASCADE option. Then deleting the record from parent table removes the records from child tables.

Hope this Helps : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

**OR**, You can follow the below syntax and create a Query.

```
DELETE 
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

I prefer the First one

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$db->quoteInto("type=?", $requestType) . $db->quoteInto("AND id =?", $requestID);
```